# How to add FluentValidationRules To Swagger in ABP Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation, abp

I want to add Validation rules to Swagger to see them in schema like in the screen. I tried to use library MicroElements.Swashbuckle.FluentValidation. But I guess it does not support AbpFluentValidation Rules or something. The only thing I get is warning on executing the application **ValidatorFactory is not provided. Please register FluentValidation.**

I tried to use library MicroElements.Swashbuckle.FluentValidation with this code:

```
[DependsOn(
    ...other modules
    typeof(AbpFluentValidationModule)
    )]
[DependsOn(typeof(CmsKitApplicationModule))]
public class MyApplicationModule : AbpModule
{
    public override void ConfigureServices(ServiceConfigurationContext context)
    {
        //.. other services
        context.Services.AddFluentValidationRulesToSwagger(options =>
        {
            options.SetNotNullableIfMinLengthGreaterThenZero = true;
            options.UseAllOffForMultipleRules = true;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you have installed the `FluentValidation.AspNetCore` package.In your `Startup.cs` or equivalent module, ensure FluentValidation is added to the services. something like this `services.AddFluentValidation(fv => fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<SomeValidator>())`. Replace `SomeValidator` with a validator from your project.make sure that the `AbpFluentValidationModule` is properly set up. check Swashbuckle is correctly configured in your application. check the application log if there anything useful information we can find.